# back button and up button don't work when parent activity is started from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a broadcast receiver that starts an activity A using the following code

```
            Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, A.class);
              appIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
              context.startActivity(appIntent);
```

the A activity starts ok, and then inside I press a button that starts another activity B using this code

```
            TaskStackBuilder tsb = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            tsb.addParentStack(this);
            Intent intent=new Intent(this, B.class);
            tsb.addNextIntent(intent);
            tsb.startActivities();
```

activity B starts fine, but is I press back button or up button activity A doesn't show up

here is the definition of both activities in manifest fiel

```
    <activity android:name=".A"  android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".B" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:parentActivityName="myPackage.A">
        <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="myPackage.A" />
    </activity>
```

and in activity B I have the following code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simplelistlayout);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   moveTaskToBack(true); 
   B.this.finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                        .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                        .startActivities();
            } else {
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
};
```

---

I tried to debug and I think the problem is when I call activity A from the broadcast receiver the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK causes the intent to have both action (android.intent.action.MAIN) and category (android.intent.category.LAUNCHER) and activity A is not my launcher activity, so when activity B receives the back action or the up button is pressed I see the intend having activity A correctly but with the action and category of the launcher activity, how can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you starting `B` from `A` in this complicated manner? Why don't you just start `B` using `Intent intent=new Intent(this, B.class); startActivity(intent);` ? This may be causing you problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you press BACK in `B`, it executes this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   moveTaskToBack(true); 
   B.this.finish();
}
```

This moves the task to the background, which is why you won't see activity A. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I changed it now to 

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}

but still the same problem.
I think the main problem is that activity A doesn't have the Action Main or the Category Launcher, but when I debug the application I find the Intent in the Up action have both the Action and the Category.

Comment: the same behavior appear if you press the back button or the Up button.

Comment: Hi, I found many links suggesting that there is a problem with the NavUtils.navigateUpTo in jellybeans and up, so I replaced it in the code with                upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(upIntent);
finish();
and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the calling to activity A in my broadcast receiver to

```
Intent appIntent=new Intent(context, A.class);
appIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
context.startActivity(appIntent);
```

and the call to Activity B to

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

and now it is working